# android- How to make step by step wizard

Tags: android

I want to make a registration form for my application . 
I want to ask a few question in each step. I want to have 3 steps and users should move to next step upon completion of previous step.

How can I do something like this in android in one activity?

Comment: https://github.com/romannurik/Android-WizardPager

Comment: https://github.com/TechFreak/WizardPager

Answer (score 9):

You can use a combination of `Fragments` and `ViewPager` to accomplish your task!

**Recommended ViewPager Tutorials :**

1. http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/04/example-of-viewpager-with-custom.html
2. https://awesoham.wordpress.com/2013/10/05/tutorial-using-a-button-to-switch-pages-in-a-viewpager-android-studio/
3. http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

You can use fragments. You can make each your step a fragment and when user answers your questions you can jump to next step.(fragment)

You can check fragments from here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

If your steps are independent from each other you can put your fragments in a viewpager and make your steps slidable.

Here is a popular view pager library with indicator. (You can use indicators to notice current step)
https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Check my below answer and Use this awesome solution using latest `ConstaintLayout` released. I have made checkout process in horizontal steps with progressbar.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42694364/4862126

I have made this without using any library.
[image]