# Android: How can I achieve layout like this?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, layout, android-relativelayout

[image]

I am able to do this using below code. But problem is "Shipping Address" and "1" **TextView** must be centered to vertical line(below "1" there should be center of "Shipping Address" **TextView**).

**neccesary_part_of_layout.xml**

```
       <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fcm_rl_scroll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp">


            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/mProgressBar"
                style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:progress="100"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_bar"
                android:secondaryProgress="100"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fcm_tv_step1"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/mProgressBar"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mProgressBar"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/mProgressBar"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_round_filled_white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp16" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fcm_tv_step1text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fcm_tv_step1"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp40"
                android:text="Shopping Address"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp16" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fcm_tv_step22"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/mProgressBar"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mProgressBar"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/mProgressBar"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fcm_tv_step1"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_round_filled_white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp16" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fcm_tv_step22text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fcm_tv_step22"
                android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp40"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fcm_tv_step1text"
                android:text="Address"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp16" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

### This is what I have achieved using above code:

[image]

### **Problem in Detail:**

I have white `ProgressBar`(you can take any view temporary) on which I want `TextView` with step numbers. and below each number I want step title both aligned centered to each-other.

How can I achieve this? I tried to put it in layout but that breaks dependency with progress bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally solved this using `ConstraintLayout`. Thanks to 'Google' for providing such a good layout which allows better customisation.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/checkout_hsv_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/checkout_steps_view_height"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/checkout_steps_view_margin_bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/checkout_steps_view_margin_top"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/checkout_steps_view_minwidth">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/checkout_progressbar_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/checkout_progressbar_height"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/checkout_steps_side_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/checkout_steps_side_margin"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_bar"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fcm_tv_step1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/checkout_step_small_node_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/checkout_step_small_node_size"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_round_filled_white"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:text="@string/str_checkout_step1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/checkout_step_small_node_font_size"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar2"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/progressBar2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/progressBar2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fcm_tv_step1text"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/checkout_step_name_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp10"
            android:text="@string/str_checkout_step_name1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/checkout_step_small_node_font_size"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/fcm_tv_step1"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/fcm_tv_step1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fcm_tv_step1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fcm_tv_step2"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/checkout_step_big_node_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/checkout_step_big_node_size"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/checkout_step_two_node_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/checkout_step_two_node_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_round_filled_white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/str_checkout_step2"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/checkout_step_small_node_font_size"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/fcm_tv_step1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/progressBar2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fcm_tv_step2text"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/checkout_step_name_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp10"
            android:text="@string/str_checkout_step_name2"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/checkout_step_big_node_font_size"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/fcm_tv_step2"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/fcm_tv_step2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fcm_tv_step2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fcm_tv_step3"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/checkout_step_small_node_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/checkout_step_small_node_size"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/checkout_step_two_node_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/checkout_step_two_node_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_round_filled_white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/str_checkout_step3"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/checkout_step_small_node_font_size"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/fcm_tv_step2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/progressBar2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fcm_tv_step3text"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/checkout_step_name_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp10"
            android:text="@string/str_checkout_step_name3"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/checkout_step_small_node_font_size"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/fcm_tv_step3"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/fcm_tv_step3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fcm_tv_step3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fcm_tv_step4"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/checkout_step_small_node_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/checkout_step_small_node_size"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/checkout_step_two_node_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/checkout_step_two_node_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_round_filled_white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/str_checkout_step4"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/checkout_step_small_node_font_size"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/fcm_tv_step3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/progressBar2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fcm_tv_step4text"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/checkout_step_name_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp10"
            android:text="@string/str_checkout_step_name4"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/checkout_step_small_node_font_size"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/fcm_tv_step4"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/fcm_tv_step4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fcm_tv_step4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fcm_tv_step5"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/checkout_step_small_node_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/checkout_step_small_node_size"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/checkout_step_two_node_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/checkout_step_two_node_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_round_filled_white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/str_checkout_step5"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/checkout_step_small_node_font_size"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/fcm_tv_step4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/progressBar2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fcm_tv_step5text"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/checkout_step_name_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp10"
            android:text="@string/str_checkout_step_name5"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/checkout_step_small_node_font_size"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/fcm_tv_step5"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/fcm_tv_step5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fcm_tv_step5" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Contact me if anyone wants help design this type of layout. I think I am expert now to use `ConstaintLayout`.

Comment: Hi, do you have the full sample or maybe the dimensions and background styles? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check this beautiful library for step view https://github.com/baoyachi/StepView?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=3774

> Sample

```
<com.baoyachi.stepview.HorizontalStepView
            android:id="@+id/step_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />

HorizontalStepView setpview5 = (HorizontalStepView) mView.findViewById(R.id.step_view5);
        List<StepBean> stepsBeanList = new ArrayList<>();
        StepBean stepBean0 = new StepBean("接单",1);
        StepBean stepBean1 = new StepBean("打包",1);
        StepBean stepBean2 = new StepBean("出发",1);
        StepBean stepBean3 = new StepBean("送单",0);
        StepBean stepBean4 = new StepBean("完成",-1);
        stepsBeanList.add(stepBean0);
        stepsBeanList.add(stepBean1);
        stepsBeanList.add(stepBean2);
        stepsBeanList.add(stepBean3);
        stepsBeanList.add(stepBean4);


        setpview5
                .setStepViewTexts(stepsBeanList)//总步骤
                .setTextSize(12)//set textSize
                .setStepsViewIndicatorCompletedLineColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), android.R.color.white))//设置StepsViewIndicator完成线的颜色
                .setStepsViewIndicatorUnCompletedLineColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.uncompleted_text_color))//设置StepsViewIndicator未完成线的颜色
                .setStepViewComplectedTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), android.R.color.white))//设置StepsView text完成线的颜色
                .setStepViewUnComplectedTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.uncompleted_text_color))//设置StepsView text未完成线的颜色
                .setStepsViewIndicatorCompleteIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.complted))//设置StepsViewIndicator CompleteIcon
                .setStepsViewIndicatorDefaultIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.default_icon))//设置StepsViewIndicator DefaultIcon
                .setStepsViewIndicatorAttentionIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.attention));//设置StepsViewIndicator AttentionIcon
```

Comment: In my Layout, Do I have to add multiple `<com.baoyachi.stepview.HorizontalStepView
            android:id="@+id/step_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />` with id stepview0, stepview1 till 5?