# how to so sign up activity with dots slide

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

the sign up im my app is too long and i want to split it into two steps,
something like this-
[image]

but with EditText and other things that i need for the sign up.
i want prevoius and next buttons and in that in the last step- there will be a sign up instead of the next.
i don't know how it is called, or how can you do this so i'll appricate any help!

Comment: So you want your sign-up process to be across multiple intents?

Comment: Tabs and viewpager all you need, go through it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a viewPager with the fragment of the signup screens which you need. You can then implement the fragments independently as you wish. 
Please follow the following the following tutorials for further understanding:

- [Android How to Build Intro Slider for your App](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/)
- [Slide between fragments using ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide)

You can also add a step wise progress bar. For better understanding of the user:

- [Stepper](https://androidexample365.com/show-beautiful-step-animation-especially-registration-steps/)
- [android- How to make step by step wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718440/android-how-to-make-step-by-step-wizard)